# is there any command to execute apt-get update and upgrade?

Tags: apt

I've ever wonder why there isn't a command in linux (debian and related distros) that instead of having to create an alias for a command like:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

why not upgrade would do those two tasks at once?

I understand that sometimes you just want to update the sources but why Linux doesn't have a command that does that at once so nobody would have to type a long line every time they want to update and upgrade their applications.

Comment: Switch to another distro then. Here's what I do on Arch: `pacman -Syu` `-y` for updating, `-u` for upgrading.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I like debian and for just one little thing I'm not going to switch.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Linux (the kernel). The behaviour is the same whether you use a Linux, Hurd or FreeBSD kernel in your Debian based distribution.

Comment: Well, file a bug report with a feature request for one. Perhaps they will add a command to the new apt tool.

Comment: You better use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` so the second doesn't run if the first fails (e.g. no internet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there isn't an easiest way than creating an alias, but if you want to simplify this you could do `Ctrl`+`r` and type `update`, then you could be able to see that line you executed in a certain time, then press `return` to execute it again.

```
prompt:~$
```

`Ctrl`+`r`

```
(reverse-i-search)`upda': sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I have both as an alias in .bashrc

`alias update='su -c "'"apt-get update && apt-get upgrade"'"'`

And this to remove cache and dependencies.

`alias cln='su -c "'"apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean && apt-get clean"'"'`